# What do you think are the useless tags in HTML?

Tags: html

As we are moving on to HTML5, there are some tags which now hold a very least importance that it did in the past.For example `<dl>` the defination list, I dont remember the last time used this tag.

And not only this, but there are tags which have a better and more efficient versions or just clear redundancy like `<strong>` and `<b>`, `<basefont>` and `<font>` etc.

In your Opinion, which are the tags that as a developer you can live out with?, and Which are the tags which can be ignored? because we have a better version.

Comment: If you think, this question needs to be closed, I would like hear Why?

Comment: Just look at this list: http://www.html-5.com/avoid/

Comment: I didn't vote to close it, but it is a highly subjective question, and you should consider at least tagging it as such. I can't imagine you've drafted this question as some sort of proposal to eliminate seldom-used tags in HTML5+, as this would not be the appropriate forum for that.

Comment: As with any language that has been around for many years, there are going to be functions that are not used much, and should be avoided, but, and HTML has it's share of useless tags, but, as Superstringcheese mentioned, there can be valid reasons why one person uses a tag that others thing is pointless. So, this question I think is not going to add much, but will be unbelievably subjective and could lead to pointless argments, hence why I suggested it should be closed. We can't go back and remove all these elements, as it would be too disruptive, so why have the discussion?

Comment: I dont see a reason to argue in this. My intentions were to know others developers's opinion. For example, I dont use `<dl>` but if you notice Superstringcheese answer, he uses it often and has a good reason behind it. So now I know what are reasons to use `<dl>` which is a knowledge gainer IMO.

Comment: @James Black, that was an excellent link, may be it would be better as answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you use when you want bold or italicized text if you're not using `<strong>` and `<em>`?  `<strong>` and `<em>` don't force presentation onto the page description as they are not inherently visual element, but rather descriptive (for screen readers and the like).

Comment: @mjschultz, I dont rely on HTML tags for font effects, I rather use CSS for this kinda things

Comment: @Starx: yes, but you can't use CSS to address specific word, you have to wrap them in HTML tags to identify them in the CSS.  Are you doing `<span class="effect">` or something of the sort?

Comment: Asking for opinion is a reason to close on SO. So.. voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was suggested I make this an answer, so here is an excellent page that discusses which tags and attributes should be avoided in HTML5 pages, and why, though he doesn't include elements like the `blink` tag.

http://www.html-5.com/avoid/

Comment: It's also out of date in at least one respect. The accesskey attribute is not deprecated in HTML5. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#global-attributes)

Comment: I expect that he was going by XHTML 2 which deprecated accesskey, but HTML5 continues to support it.  Also, the page was an example of what might be useful as a nice list. I focus more on elements that should be avoided than attributes anyway, as the elements help drive how I can achieve my vision on a page.

Answer (score 5):

`B` and `STRONG` are not the same thing, and neither are `I` and `EM`.

`EM` means that the text shoud be emphasised. This thus says something about how the text should be interpreted, and this is understood by screen-readers (text-to-speach), etc. It has a logical meaning. `I`, on the other hand, says nothing about the semantics -- it simply tells the HTML renderer to render the text in italic. Hence, in text, to make an emphasis, use `EM`. If you for some reason need a bit of text to be in italic without this implying that the text should be emphasised, then you can use `I`.

The same things applies to `STRONG` and `B`.

However, I really dislike `FONT`, because it says nothing about the semantics. Use `Hn` for headers, `EM` for emphasis, `CODE` for code, etc. If you lack some tag for some context, define a CSS rule like

```
  <p class="footer">...</p>
```

or

```
  <p>This is <strong class="extraordinaryEmphasis">extremely</strong> important.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

STRONG and B have distinct semantic meaning now. There was a lot of effort to clean up semantically-ambiguous elements like that. Even HR got some attention.

I use DL all the time, personally. It my workhorse KeyValuePair type. I sometimes find myself wishing it had more rigorous semantics, but then other times I'm thankful for its flexibility in allowing me to define its semantics contextually.

I suppose it depends on your definition of 'useless', which I take to mean 'having no practical use whatsoever'. I don't really know of any element in HTML5 I could say that I'll never use under any circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

P should be abandoned. No Joke. It creates artificial breaks in flowing text that can be better reproduced with a line break. Is there a P tag on a typewriter? What follows is that it becomes a "text container" that we've become dependent on for no good reason. Paragraph is a stylistic flow marker only. At most it should be a singleton tag. 
In CSS, I use it simply as a text-area container, a designation which is similar to SPAN except in block form. The P should really be a TEXTSPAN tag that can be parent to multiple spans, but not to itself. We are often forced to store some representation of P in databases, which then are impossible to reconstruct for display. Again, a double line break is much more appealing and universal.

:-)

Comment: It does not creates artificial break, it does what it is exactly supposed to do creates a paragraph. Check this http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/aabg092299a.htm to see where <p> would be appropriate instead of line break.

Comment: @Starx. Thanks, I enjoy the debate. I should restate without thee dramatics. The P tag would make more sense as a singleton, or as a simple inline designation. The problem is that it implies something that can be understood as two successive line-breaks without breaking inline flow. The only value (if any) that it provides in layout is as an anchor/bounds for a floated image/box within itself, and even that is artificial and structural.

Comment: but isn't that what block tags like <p> or <div> suppose to do?

Comment: Well, yes and no. The problem being that <p> has two roles now, a block delimiter and a text delimiter. This crosses purposes. And in many text treatments, P are not required: one-liners, tweets, comments, single words, fragments. So what do you use then as the text delimiter? Span? Span is used to style text withing text. What is missing is a <text> delimiter/tag. Then, within this delimiter, <p> could be used to define a "paragraph" if need be. In this case, <p> would not need be BLOCK but rather; inline, AND could still be a singleton.

Answer (score -1):

<code> is useless. Unless maybe you a perl one-liner fan. It should have been a semantic way to create a <pre> block - that would have been useful.

<embed> is useless. It is redundant to <object> and less capable than <object>

<small> is useless. It has no semantic meaning and should be done with CSS.

Those are my opinions of the three most useless tags that made it into the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Agreed with the current `embed`, as the name makes it sound like it should be able to embed anything, including common HTML fragments for footers/headers/navbars, but it's limited to media only, which the `video` tag obviates. Now if `embed` *could* embed .html fragments too (like iframe, but inline in the DOM), that would make it super useful for website composition, without needing client-side JS or server-side construction frameworks.

Answer (score -2):

I think that anything that indicates something that should be done in CSS is probably something that should be avoided.  This includes

```
<b>,<strong>
<i>,<em>
<center>
<u>,<strike>
```

My least favourite has be to `<font>`, as it has absoutely no meaning, and should, in all instances be replaced with a  tag.

Personally, I think it's also good to avoid HTML attributes that should be done with CSS such as "color" and "border".

Comment: +1 for 'anything that indicates something that should be done in CSS', -1 for strong and em as these are not entirely presentational.

Comment: They are not at all presentational. Like most people, the poster is unaware that tags like EM and STRONG have semantic meaning. Many modern browsers apply presentational effects to these tags unless they are overridden by CSS, but that doesn't make the tags themselves presentational.